# Footer too wide

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a footer to a webpage but am having some sizing issues I was hoping somebody could shed some light on. The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-CA">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>
    Home
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none">
        <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo_text">
        </a>
        <span class="tabs">
        <a class="link" href="page1.html">Tab1</a>
        <a class="link" href="page2.html">Tab2</a>
        <a class="link" href="page3.html">Tab3</a>
        <a class="link" href="page4.html">Tab4</a>
        </span>
        <img id="combologo" src="combo.png" alt="combologo_text" align="right">
    </div>  
    <div id="scrollarea">
        <marquee class="scroller" scrollamount="15">
        <span id="scrolltext1">
        Text
        </span>
        <span id="scrolltext2">
        Text 
        </span>
        <span id="scrolltext3">
        Text 
        </span>
        </marquee><br>
    </div>
    <div class="contentleft">
        <h2 class="pagetitle">
        This is the header
        </h2>
        <p>
        Body Text<br><br>
        Body Text<br><br>
        Body Text
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <img class="bottomlogo" src="logo.png" alt="bottomlogo_text" align="right">         
        <br><br>2016<br>
        This Website Is Still Under Construction - Coming Soon!
    </div>
</body>
```

The corresponding style sheet looks like this:

```
html {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%
}

body {
     margin: 0;
     font-family: rexlia;
     font-size: 1vw;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: url(cubes.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
}

hr {
   border-color: black;
   background-color: black;
   color: black;
   margin: 0;
}

.logo {
      width: 20%;
      margin-top: 2%;
      margin-left: 2%;
      text-decoration: none;
}

.link {
      margin-right: 3%; 
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: transparent;
}

.link:hover {
            color: white;
            background-color: rgb(80,80,80);
}

.header {
        font-style: italic;
        background: rgb(80,80,80);
        background: -webkit- linear-gradient(rgb(80,80,80), white);
        background: -o-linear- linear-gradient(rgb(80,80,80), white);
        background: -moz-linear- linear-gradient(rgb(80,80,80), white);
        background: linear-gradient(rgb(80,80,80), white);
        padding-bottom: 0.7%;
}

.scroller {
          font-size: 2vw;
          color: white;
}

#scrollarea {
            background: rgb(80,80,80);
            padding-top: 1%;
            padding-bottom: 1%;
            font-style: italic;
}

.pagetitle {
           font-style: italic;
 }

.contentleft {
             padding-left: 2%;
             padding-top: 1%;
             float: left;
             width: 45%;
}

.footer {
        clear: both;
        background: rgb(80,80,80);
        background: -webkit- linear-gradient(white, rgb(80,80,80));
        background: -o-linear- linear-gradient(white, rgb(80,80,80));
        background: -moz-linear- linear-gradient(white, rgb(80,80,80));
        background: linear-gradient(white, rgb(80,80,80));
        text-align: right;
        font-style: italic;
        padding: 2%;
        width: 100%;
}

.tabs {
      margin-left: 3%;
      color: black;
}

.bottomlogo {
             width: 6%;
}

#combologo {
           width: 13%;
           margin-top: 1%;
           margin-right: 2%;
}

#scrolltext1 {
             margin-right: 100%;
}

#scrolltext2 {
             margin-right: 100%;
}

#cubes {
       width: 45%;
}
```

I've stripped it down as to simplify the issue, but basically the problem I'm having is this: The Header, scroll bar (marquee) and the body are all the same width. The footer for some reason, is wider than the rest. As you can see the html block is set to 1005, then the body is set to 100% of that, so with the footer set to 100% also, shouldn't it be 100% of it's parent element (body)? If I take the 100% out is works, but I'm trying to figure out why it's doing what it's doing. Sorry, I'm really new to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem caused by adding `padding` to a defined `width` of 100%. You can either remove the `width:100%`, it is not needed, divs cover 100% of parent anyway.

If you want to keep that width then you could add the `box-sizing` CSS property to make sure padding/borders do not affect the total width/height calculation.

```
footer {
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

---

Examples:

```css
footer {
  padding:1em;
  background:lightblue;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}

footer:nth-of-type(1) {
  width:100%;
}

footer:nth-of-type(2) {
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<footer>footer with padding and 100% width</footer>
<footer>footer with padding and 100% width and box-sizing</footer>
<footer>footer with padding</footer>
```

Comment: Doesn't the padding only affect the inside of the footer though? Shouldn't it still maintain it's outside dimensions (100% width of the body in this case)?

Comment: No, you see, padding adds space outside the content but inside the element, therefore affecting its dimension. Width of 100% and padding of 2% would result in a 104% wide div.

Comment: Ah ok, that's good to know. I didn't think padding would resize the element as long as the content with padding did not exceed the element size. That makes perfect sense now. Thanks.